# How do I send a low size black and white image using plain text SMS without utilizing EMS/MMS?

Tags: java-me, mobile, sms, mms

I want to send very low size black and white images using plain text SMS without utilizing EMS/MMS. Searching on the net yielded some results which contained hints that logos are sent using SMSs, which make use of the User Data Header in an SMS. But it is not clear exactly how to approach the code. I want to send the message from my PC to any low cost phone (regardless of whether the phone contains J2ME or any other programming support or not). The images can be described in binary form in <140 bytes or sometimes will require it to be split into two parts if greater than 140. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to [enconde a binary SMS](http://sw.nokia.com/id/23e93d2d-0f25-4799-9b03-1ec9b5cf775a/Smart_Messaging_FAQ_v2_0.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to send an image using Nokia's [OTA Bitmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OTA_bitmap) specification, but it requires 3 SMS messages and is usually used for images that are 72px x 28px.  Older Nokia's could use it as a screen saver but that was a long time ago (e.g. 2004 was that last time I saw it) and I don't think the newer handsets allow this.

A bit more info at under generic "[smart messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Messaging)" at Wikipedia.